# Using USB as a slave

Tags: usb, driver

is it possible to have the Rpi act as a USB slave/device. I would like to be able to connect its usb to the USB of a standard computer, have the host machine recognize the RPI as a USB disk and then programmatically deal with the incoming data.

Any pointers, further reading etc is always welcome

Comment: The new IO board shipped with Compute Module Development Kit seems to have USB slave connector... how can one get it working?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the above issue.  The other issue asks about using the Power microUSB port.  This issue is asking about using USB-OTG through the other USB ports.

Comment: @TimLudwinski I deleted our dialog to prevent confusion since I agreed with you about the previous dupe and re-opened this, but I'm now agreeing with Chetan about the newer question.

Comment: Yes, these do look like the same question (although the answer in this one is more what I was looking for).

Answer (score 6):

The Model B uses a SMSC LAN9512 USB 2.0 Hub and 10/100 Ethernet Controller IC to provide multiple physical USB host ports from the single USB OTG port available on the Broadcom SoC.

The presence of this hub IC prevents the USB ports from being used in slave mode. However, as the Model A does not have this IC present and instead just has a single USB port connected directly to the SoC's OTG port it should be possible to configure it to act in slave mode through software.

As the Model A has a female host USB port, a HOST to HOST conversion cable will be needed.

Please see this Raspberry Pi Forum thread for more details: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=15696

Comment: Yes, you can use a Model A as a USB slave device:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=74098

Although it's quite limited to just usage as a mass storage device ( SD card)
- no GPIO access, display or even ARM CPU usage.

Comment: This post discusses this issue: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=35712

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the exact link on the exact forum right now, but I recall this is an open hardware-related issue.
Short answer: everything is there on the board, but it's not
wired. And eventually (don't remember) some passive components are missing. IIRC the pi folks advertised this as a cool, non-trivial task they hope someone do... In any case be prepared to solder some wires on a Surface-Mounted-components-Only (that is, tiny) PCB :(
The "somewhat official" wiki mentions it, but with no detail whatsoever.
http://elinux.org/RPi_Tasks#OTG_device_mode

How can I tag *your* question as **non-trivial**? ;)