# USB 3.0 OTG on Raspberry Pi 4 (USB gadget)

Tags: usb, gadget, usb3, otg

Raspberry Pi 4 can do USB OTG via the USB-C connector (according to [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73911)) - but only at USB 2.0 speeds since the USB-C connector only connects to USB 2.0 lanes.

My question is - can Pi 4 also do OTG at USB 3.0 speeds? Maybe via the standard Type-A connectors?

Answer (score 4):

No it cannot. No device can do OTG via Type-A sockets, they are host-only.

For the sake of completeness, as @jdonald mentioned in a comment, RPi model A/A+ (the ones without the USB hub, just like Zero) can be configured into device mode and connected to a USB host using a non-standard cable. However, this is excluded for any model B (including RPi 4), as there is a hub in the way.

Comment: Raspberry Pi A and A+ do OTG via type-A sockets. The difference is that such connectors lack the OTG pin for switching dynamically so the A/A+ needs to be fixed into device mode on boot via `dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral`.

Comment: @jdonald Physically, you can wire USB to any connector with sufficient pin count. I've seen USB over 3.5mm jack for instance. However, this is not something you can legally put a USB logo on.

Comment: Help me out, please... your comment here implies that your answer is guided by a requirement that the only possibilities worth considering are those to which a USB logo can be legally applied. In other words, @jdonald comment is accurate, but not "legal"??

Comment: @Seamus Sorry, I didn't get your question. Are you talking about the Pi model A, or the Pi 4 (which has no "A" model)?