# Can I turn a Pi + HDMI Display into a USB monitor?

Tags: usb, display, otg

Would it be possible to turn a Pi + HDMI display into a USB monitor?
The Pi with the monitor would act as a 2nd display.

(note that I'm not looking to avoid buying a USB monitor, I want to build an external gadget that incorporates a 2nd display)

1. I see that the Pi can act as a USB OTG "gadget"/device:
   https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41
   But I don't see monitor listed.
2. I see that the PiKVM has chosen to incorporate hardware HDMI capture
   https://pikvm.org/
   But this could be because USB monitors aren't supported at say, the bios screen, which is required for their use case.

Is it technically possible?

Do USB monitors require a special driver on Windows, or are they a standard USB class device?

What kind of code would have to be written on the Pi side to support this if it can't do it already?

Comment: *"I see that the Pi can act as a USB OTG "gadget"/device"* -> That's a limited range of models and even with the Pi 4, limited to USB 2.0 speeds: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/102294/5538 And while it may be possible in theory, I do not think there is software around to do it.

Comment: what do you want to use it for?

Comment: I was thinking of building a personal videoconferencing device:
- Connects to a PC with a single USB cable
- Has a typical web cam ring light
- Sits on a tripod that would be taller than a typical laptop screen
- Has a web cam
- Has a small screen, that to the PC looks like a 2nd screen

This could be done with a phone, or separate components and a USB hub.  But if a Pi could be turned into a USB monitor, it would bring few parts together.