# Raspberry pi 4 as usb drive using the attached hdd

Tags: raspbian

I am new here, and have a question I can’t find any answers for.
So basically, i have a pi4 running as a file server on local host with an attached 4tb hdd, using samba. I can reach it with my tv using plex or other media servers, but my problem is that my vidos are very high bitrates, so the playback is lugging on tv, while on computer I can watch them flawlessly through my network, nonproblem. If i connect the storage to the tv via usb, there is no problem, so the tv is not an issue.
So my idea was, to connect the pi to the tv via usb and see the hdd content as a mass storage, and the same time the file server could run as well.
I found the usb gadget solution, but that uses a container file to mount as storage, so my question is, is there a workaround to mount a physical drive instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is particularly Pi specific, as it could be applied to any PC running a SAMBA file share. However, if I am wrong, then it is a possible duplicate of [Pi as a USB client](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/22515/26774)